# TimePicker looks different on different versions of Android

Tags: android, alarmmanager, datetimepicker, clock, android-timepicker

I was recently working on the TimePicker and checked the output on different phones. For the Android version 5.0 and above this is what it looks like. Its exactly the same as i thought while designing. 
[As of in Android 5.0 and above](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dInmM.jpg)

and for the devices which are lower than 5.0 the UI looks different.

[Looks pretty old](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cXWfO.png)

Isn't there any option where i can have a common TimePicker (Analog clock) which runs on all the versions?

Comment: try this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/16265822/3678308 and http://stackoverflow.com/a/9681744/3678308

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Android provides controls for the user to pick a time or pick a date as ready-to-use dialogs. Each picker provides controls for selecting each part of the time (hour, minute, AM/PM) or date (month, day, year).Reference [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9681744/3678308) and [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16265822/3678308)